# ¿Por qué no incrementa la primera variable del bucle for? (Java)

Tags: java

¡Buenas StackOverflow!
Como ya se lee en el título, tengo dos bucles for anidados para recorrer un array bidimensional llamada "matrix".

matrix lleva los siguientes datos:

```
int matrix[][] = {{1, 1, 1, 0, 
                   0, 5, 0, 1, 
                   2, 1, 3, 10 }};
```

Perfecto, pues yo recorro el array de esta manera:

```
for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
  for(int x = 0; x < matrix[0].length; x++) {
         //code...
  }
}
```

Pero lo que me da esta operación es que la variable "i" siempre es 0 y la "x" supera con creces el largo de matrix[0] dándome posiciones tales como (0, 10) (0,11)...

Si alguien me pudiera ayudar...
¡Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: El segundo for debería ser `matrix[i].length`

Comment: Ya lo he probado amigo, y me sigue dando los mismos resultados... 
Es, como poco, extraño lo que está pasando aquí.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como lo tienes, estás definiendo una matriz, cuyo tamaño es de 1 X 12 elementos (Por eso la posicion 10 y 11 son validas).
Si lo que quieres es tener una matriz de 4 x 3, tienes que definirla así:

```
public class MyClass {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    int matrix[][] = {{1, 1, 1, 0}, 
              { 0, 5, 0, 1}, 
              { 2, 1, 3, 10 }};
               
    for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
       System.out.println("Imprimiendo fila " + i);
       for(int x = 0; x < matrix[i].length; x++) {  //En tu código la tienes como matrix[0].length
          System.out.println(matrix[i][x]);
       }
    }
  }   
}
```

Retorna:

```
Imprimiendo fila 0
1
1
1
0
Imprimiendo fila 1
0
5
0
1
Imprimiendo fila 2
2
1
3
10
```

Comment: Funcionó perfectamente, muchas gracias Pipe. 
Me había liado con la sintaxis de las arrays usando llaves.

Comment: Con mucho gusto